# Java application not working on other systems

Tags: java, cross-platform, inno-setup

I've made a word-processor named StoryTeller in Java (a first - beta version, which I'm still working on improving) and put it online for others to test out and use.

I've gotten a response saying they were unable to open it. I've built and run StoryTeller on Windows 10 OS and it works fine. After generating the jar file, I used Inno setup to generate an installer for the program. You can find the file I've uploaded [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/ansts4dkqlnpafo/StoryTeller_v1.0b.exe?dl=0). Here's the message I got about it:

> Hello! I was going to try out StoryTeller on my Macbook today, but unfortunately it didn't work. The file automatically gets opened in
>   "Text Editor" where encrypted text shows up along with the error
>   message "this program must be run under Win32".
>
> I downloaded it on my old computer earlier this week (it has windows
>   7) and the download process and installation worked perfectly fine,
>   but I was unable to open the program when the installation was done.
>   It appeared on my desk as a Java-symbol (the icon) and nothing
>   happened when I clicked on it. Both my OS are quite old (Macbook from
>   2010 and the other computer from 2012), but I've still updated them as
>   much as possible and installed all the latest versions available of
>   necessary programs, so I'm not sure whether the problem lies within my
>   computers or StoryTeller itself.
>
> Do you have any ideas how I can fix this? I would really like to try
>   StoryTeller since it seems to be a great concept that could really
>   come in handy when I work on my novel.

Could anyone help, please, understand what may be the issue here? Thanks.

Comment: `.exe` is a windows only format

Comment: ok. i'll see if i can find how to make it for other platforms then. but still why would it not work on that windows 7?

Answer (score 1):

- First, check if your JDK is 32-bits and make sure to advice your future users have a 32-bit JRE installed. This way, it may work properly. I think 64-bit Java apps can't run atop a 32-bit JRE;
- You can bundle a proper JRE/JVM with your software;
- Make sure you are referencing ANYTHING with absolute paths inside your code. This could make your software throw several exceptions when running somewhere else;

For instance, Inno-setup commonly generates Windows-only `.exe` setups. Installing your software in a Mac would require you to generate a `.dmg` or `.pkg` (this one you could create through PackageMaker extension from XCode [here](https://developer.apple.com/downloads/index.action?name=PackageMaker) (require registration, more info [here](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/4083583?start=0&tstart=0)

> Kappy on Jul 5, 2012 6:28 PM says: Go to connect.apple.com and search for "packagemaker." Of course you must first be logged into your developer account.

))

For Linux, you can provide a simple shellscript bundled with your `.jar` (even with a discrete JVM) in a `.zip` or `.tar.gz` file, and ask your future users to run the provided shellscript.

Good luck!